# How to make a Soap request with security specifications

Tags: php, web-services, soap, ws-security

I am a beginner in integrations with webservices using XML and Soap and I'm having difficulty developing my request using security specs.

According to the integration documentation, the requisition must contain the following safety specifications:

### Digital Signature

- Signature Algorithm: RSA-SHA256 (http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsigmore#rsa-sha256)
- Signature Canonicalization: C14N-exc (http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#)
- Digest Algorithm: SHA256 (http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256)
- SignatureTarget:

  - Timestamp (Namespace: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-security-utility-1.0.xsd)
  - Body (Namespace: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/)
- Issuer's public key communicated through IssuerSerial (Namespace: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#)

### Cryptography

- Symmetric Encoding Algorithm: 3DES-CBC
- Key Transport Algorithm: RSA-OAEP
- Receiver public key communicated through IssuerSerial
- Encryption Target:

  - Body (Namespace: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/)

My SSL certificate: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.apasp.net.br

Below is my current Soap request:

```
$xmlRequest = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:w="http://www.cip-bancos.org.br/ARQ/WSCC011.xsd" xmlns:s="http://www.cip-bancos.org.br/ARQ/ASCC011.xsd" xmlns:wt="http://www.cip-bancos.org.br/schemas/WSTIPOS.xsd">
                <soapenv:Header>
                </soapenv:Header>
                <soapenv:Body>
                <w:WSCC011Request>
                    <w:CabecalhoReq>
                        <wt:NumCtrlEmis></wt:NumCtrlEmis>
                        <wt:ISPBEmissor></wt:ISPBEmissor>
                        <wt:ISPBDestinatario></wt:ISPBDestinatario>
                        <wt:DtHrEmis></wt:DtHrEmis>
                        <wt:DtRef></wt:DtRef>
                        <wt:DomSis></wt:DomSis>
                        <wt:NUop></wt:NUop>
                    </w:CabecalhoReq>
                    <w:Corpo>
                        <w:ASCC011>
                            <s:Grupo_ASCC011_Consigrio>
                                <IdentdPartAdmdo></IdentdPartAdmdo>
                                <NumCtrlConsigrio></NumCtrlConsigrio>
                                <CNPJBaseEnte></CNPJBaseEnte>
                                <NumConsigrioEnte></NumConsigrioEnte>
                                <NumDigtConsigrioEnte></NumDigtConsigrioEnte>
                                <Grupo_ASCC011_Consignc>
                                    <NumCPFServdr></NumCPFServdr>
                                    <IdentcServdr></IdentcServdr>
                                    <IdentcOrgao></IdentcOrgao>
                                    <CNPJBaseOrgaoPagdr></CNPJBaseOrgaoPagdr>
                                    <IdentcEsp></IdentcEsp>
                                    <TpParcmnt></TpParcmnt>
                                    <QtdTotParcl></QtdTotParcl>
                                    <DiaVencParcl></DiaVencParcl>
                                    <DtIniAvebc></DtIniAvebc>
                                    <DtFimAvebc></DtFimAvebc>
                                    <VlrParcl></VlrParcl>
                                    <VlrTotAvebc></VlrTotAvebc>
                                    <NumOpConsigncConsigrio></NumOpConsigncConsigrio>
                                </Grupo_ASCC011_Consignc>
                            </s:Grupo_ASCC011_Consigrio>
                        </w:ASCC011>
                    </w:Corpo>
                </w:WSCC011Request>
                </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>';
        try {
            $client = new SoapClient('https://www.hext.portaldoconsignado.org.br/ws/WSCC011', array('trace' => 1));
            $soapBody = new \SoapVar($xmlRequest, \XSD_ANYXML);
            $return = $client->__soapCall('WSCC011', array());

            echo '<pre>' . var_export($return, true) . '<pre>';
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo(htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()));
        }
```

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: I have never worked with SOAP in PHP. But from my own SOAP/WS-* experience I would not even try getting this to work from PHP until you have a working client in either Java or .NET. Simple SOAP is simple XML, but once WS-security comes into the mix, it becomes very complex and IMO requires library support.